# odd squarefree and squareful neighbors

Tags: number-theory

There are squarefree numbers $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i$, $k \gt 1$ so that $n+2$ is not squarefree (e.g. $115+2=3^2.13$).
Are there infinite many such $n$?
Are there numbers n with arbitrarely many prime-factors?
Are these also infinite?

Comment: An elementary sieve argument will show that the set of squarefree $n\equiv 7\pmod{9}$ has positive density. This answers your first question in the affirmative. For any $k$, the set of numbers with at most $k$ prime factors has density zero; hence, your latter two questions also have "yes" as the answer.

Comment: Note that the term "squareful" is not the same as "not squarefree". For example, $3^2\cdot 13$ is neither squareful, nor squarefree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, yes and yes, since by the Dirichlet theorem, there are an infinite number of primes of the form $9k+7$ or $9k+1$.

Comment: above n should be Composite - edited the post